# Fb.ui feed share dialog box crop image after share

Tags: javascript, ajax, facebook, share, fb.ui

**Here is My Code Below **  I Try to share dynamic image from my website to facebook using fb.ui feed dialog box. here is my code of share dialog box. but image was crop after the image was share. i share screen short with you,

```
function share_prompt()
{
    document.getElementById('shareImg').setAttribute("style","height:370px");
var element = $("#shareImg");
        var getCanvas;
     html2canvas(element, {
     onrendered: function (canvas) {

             var base64Image = canvas.toDataURL();

            console.log(base64Image);

            $.ajax({
                url: "save_image.php",
                type:"POST",
                data: {image: base64Image, id: <?php echo $t; ?> },
                success: function(response)
                {
                    $("#shareImg").css({
                            "height": "",

                        });
                      FB.ui(
                           {
                             method: 'feed',
                             name: 'What do you Think For This?',
                             link: 'http://voteit.in/que_detail.php?pid=<?php echo $pid ?>',

                             picture: 'http://voteit.in/poll_result/<?php echo $t ?>.png',
                             caption: 'www.voteit.in',
                             description: 'Your Friends has Already Given There opinions For Above Question. Provide Yours!',
                             author : 'voteit.in',


                             message: ''

                           },
                           function(response) {
                             if (response && response.post_id) {

                             } else {
                              // alert('Post was not published.');
                             }
                           }
                         );

                }
            });
           // $("#previewImage").append(canvas);
            //getCanvas = canvas;

         }

     });
```

}

[In Mac After Sharing Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lpSOm.png)

Comment: side note: you should never use FB.ui in an asynchronous callback, it must be called directly on user interaction. browsers may block the popup.

Comment: browser popup allow but image was crop after share

Comment: i know, it was just a side note. you should never do that. and don´t allow the popup, users would not do that. browser block FB.ui dialogs for a good reason, dialogs should only open on user interaction (mouse click)

Comment: after open dialog box its display image perfectly but after the share its should bi display image croped

Comment: problem happen only on google crome in mac os

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#images